# JBoss7 with updating hibernate 4.3 fails to start

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

I tried to update hibernate version to 4.3.7 in the modules of JBoss7 ( 7.1.1.Final) but it failed to start with following errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @152b4053 (roots: /Users/sini/dev/jboss7-dt/modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
```

I've just followed the JBoss7.1 document in the below link being stuck with the above error.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion

Is there anyone ran into the issue and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 4.3 is for JPA 2.1/Java EE 7, whereas JBoss AS 7 only supports JPA 2.0/Java EE 6.

I don't think you can upgrade to anything higher than Hibernate 4.2.x by simply updating the Hibernate modules.